# Can Neo4j be embedded into a Unity application for Android/IOS tablets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, neo4j

If not is there a way to build it on both devices, independent of the application, and then have it be accessible from inside the app?

Answer (score 1):

The possible approach I see here is having the 2-part infrastructure based on API. For this purpose you need to be really eager to learn networking at least a bit, however it has many benefits for the future.

- Unity app as a networking client sending API calls to your back-end server (currently Unity supports WebGL and UDP low level transport API https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html). These API calls can be in the form of data-interchange format like *JSON* or *XML*. JSON example: ["signup", {"name": "SomeUser", "pass": "SomePass123"}]
- Back-end network server client, which receives the calls. Logic for writing to and reading from the database is purely in this back-end. It sends the result back to the client again in the form of some data-interchange format. *JSON* example: ["success"]

This way your Unity app will be absolutely independent from any kind of database. If you will want to change the database in the future, you just rework your database handling on the back-end while reusing same API calls! Or you can have multiple front-end client apps based on different technologies accessing the same API.

**Now the approaches to Unity and networking for your custom back-end:**

- **High level approach**

  For pure Unity-based networking you can use Photon
  (https://www.photonengine.com/en/PUN) or Unity High Level networking
  API (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingHLAPI.html).
- **Lower level approach**

  You can have your back-end based on entirely different technology
  too! In that case for Unity client app use Unity's low level
  networking Transport Layer
  (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html) and your
  back-end's networking layer can be based e.g. on Python (e.g.
  *Twisted*), JavaScript (e.g. *NodeJS*) or any other.
- **Even Lower Level approach**

  You can go even deeper and use *.NET Sockets* for Unity client (but
  you need to have Unity Pro subscription, otherwise they don't let
  you build your app) and any low level socketing libraries for
  back-end, e.g. C# *.NET Socket* again, Python *socket* or, bit
  higher level, *socketserver*.

  **WARNING!**

  Note that if you want to port your app for browser, you must use websocket, not TCP/UDP.

**Neo4j on different back-ends:**

- C# (.NET) - https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/
- JAVA - https://neo4j.com/developer/java/
- JavaScript - https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/
- Python - https://neo4j.com/developer/python/

Answer (score 0):

Not really, there is an older version of [Neo4j ported to Android](http://neo4j.com/blog/new-incubator-project-neo4j-mobile-for-android-v0-1/) (Neo4j 1.5).

Otherwise there is a [Swift/iOS](https://github.com/GraphStory/neo4j-ios) driver (and of course java drivers) for Neo4j.

Comment: Link to the Theo Swift/iOS driver for posterity: https://github.com/GraphStory/neo4j-ios